# Why is my Read Method being called when I click update on the inline editing of a grid row

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Another frustrating day with the Kendo Grid. Anyway, my problem is this: When I click "Edit" on a grid row item, it goes into edit mode. Good. Then I modify a record, and click update. I would expect the "/Company/SaveAccountAdmin" method to be called.But no... The read method is called again. When I click "Cancel" the record just disappears! The $("#save") click event is just an attempt to force a save, but surely these events can be triggered off the grid command buttons? Any ideas anyone?

```
/// <reference path="../kendo.all-vsdoc.js" />

$(document).ready(function () {

var CompanyId = $("#CompanyId").val();

var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(
  {
      batch: true,
      pageSize: 10,

      transport: {
          create: {
              url: "/Company/SaveAccountAdmin",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              url: "/Company/ReadAccountAdmin",
          },

          read: {
              url: "/Company/ReadAccountAdmin"
          },

          update: {
              url: "/Company/SaveAccountAdmin",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              url: "/Company/ReadAccountAdmin",
          },
          //destroy: {},
          parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
              if (operation !== "read" && options.model) {
                  return { model: kendo.stringify(options.model) };
              }
          }
      },

      schema: {

          model: {
              id: "ComanyContactId",
              fields: {
                  CompanyId: { type: "number", editable: false, nullable: false, defaultVaue: CompanyId },
                  CompanyContactId: { type: "number", editable: false, defaultValue: 0 },
                  FirstName: { type: "string", nullable: false, validation: { required: true } },
                  LastName: { type: "string", nullable: false, validation: { required: true } },
                  Email: { type: "string", nullable: false, validation: { required: true } },
                  Phone: { type: "string", nullable: false, validation: { required: true } },
                  IsActive: { type: "boolean" }
              }
          }
      }
  });

$("#save").click(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var rows = $.map(dataSource.data(), function (value, index) {

        return {
            CompanyId: value["CompanyId"],
            CompanyContactId: value["CompanyContactId"],
            FirstName: value["FirstName"],
            LastName: value["LastName"],
            Email: value["Email"],
            Phone: value["Phone"],
            IsActive: value["IsActive"]
        }
    });


    var jsonCompanyContacts = JSON.stringify(rows);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Company/SaveAccountAdmin',
        type: 'POST',
        traditional: true,
        data: { "jsonCompanyContacts": jsonCompanyContacts },
        success: alert("Data Saved")
    })
});


$("#AccountAdmins").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    toolbar: ["create"],

    editable: "inline",
    sortable: true,
    pageable: true,
    navigatable: true,
    editable: "inline",
    columns: [
        { field: "CompanyId", title: "CompanyID", sortable: true },
        { field: "CompanyContactId", title: "Company ContactID", sortable: true },
        { field: "FirstName", title: "First Name", sortable: true },
        { field: "LastName", title: "Last Name" },
        { field: "Email", title: "Email", },
        { field: "Phone", title: "Phone", },
        { field: "IsActive", title: "Is Active" },
        { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "210px" }]

});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that it is because you have the Read URL set for the Update command:

```
      update: {
          url: "/Company/SaveAccountAdmin", // <-- Not used because it is changed below
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          url: "/Company/ReadAccountAdmin", // <-- Read URL set
      },
```

Comment: Well spotted! I've been through so many combinations on this grid I cant see straight anymore.